# Delete a list from collection of lists

Tags: python, list

I have collection of lists like this:

```
example = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],[ ],['z'],['g','h','i'],[ ],['z']]
```

I want to remove `[]` and `['z']` from the list.
The desired output is:

```
example = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

How can I do it? Can I remove both using an one liner?
I am familiar with `.pop()` and `.remove()` command but I have doubts if it will work for [ ] type of list.

Comment: do you care the performance loss if recreate a new list?

Comment: I don't really , as i am gonna use it inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for the filtering:

```py
example = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],[ ],['z'],['g','h','i'],[ ],['z']]

output = [sublst for sublst in example if sublst not in ([], ['z'])]
print(output) # [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove them like this:

```
example = list(filter(lambda val: val !=  [] and val!=['z'], example))
```